# how align this navbar <li> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

how to align this dropdown?

if i add padding value on
.nav ul li

then the dropdown menu not in center

sry for my english

[this is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CQy6.png)

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. integer mi
tortor, imperdiet sed hendrit non, consequat luctus magna. nullam
accumsan odio ac lectus mollis finibus.

sry i add lorem ibsum bcoz stackoverflow cant post my question

```css
/* GLOBAL STYLE */
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    font-family: cambria, "Times New Roman", serif;
}

.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0 20px;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 15px, -1px 0px 15px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

/* HEADER */
.header {
    height: 95px;
    background: url('image/mywebsite_logo.png') no-repeat 10px 10px;
}

.header .ads {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

/* NAV BAR */

.nav ul {
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}

.nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    text-align: center;

} 

.nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

.nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: white;
}

.nav ul li .submenu {
    display: none;
}

.nav ul li:hover .submenu {
    display: block;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.nav ul li:hover .submenu li {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 16px 10px 0px;
}

.nav ul li .submenu li:hover {
    background-color: greenyellow;
}

.nav ul li .submenu2 {
    display: none;
}

.nav ul li:hover .submenu2 {
    display: block;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.nav ul li:hover .submenu2 li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 41px 9px 10px;
}

.nav ul li .submenu2 li:hover {
    background-color: greenyellow;
}

/* NAVBAR */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mywebsite | The best, awesome website ever by Aufa Riduan Cahyadi C030319100</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_fixed.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- HEADER -->
        <div class="header">
            <a href="iklan.html">
                <img src="image/ads_horizontal.png" class="ads">
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- MENU NAVIGASI -->
        <div class="nav">
            <ul class="topmenu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li class="down"><a href="#">Categories</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">MySQL</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Product</a>
                    <ul class="submenu2">
                        <li><a href="#">eBook</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Buku</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
                    </ul>
                
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            <br class="clear">
        </div>
        
        <div class="sidebar">
            <img src="image/gambar4.jpg">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">MySQL</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="image/ads280.png">
            </a>
        </div>

        
        <div class="main">
            <div class="article">
                <h1>Our Best Awesome Article #1</h1>
                <img src="image/gambar1.jpg">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. integer mi
                    tortor, imperdiet sed hendrit non, consequat luctus magna. nullam
                    accumsan odio ac lectus mollis finibus.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Aliquam a lectus porta, bibendum enim id, dictum nunc. duis tincidunt
                    sed turpis non suscipit. Nunc id mi molestie, porta leo id, vulputate eros.
                </p>
            </div>
            <hr class="clear">
            <div class="article">
                <h1>Our Best Awesome Article #2</h1>
                <img src="image/gambar2.jpg">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. integer mi
                    tortor, imperdiet sed hendrit non, consequat luctus magna. nullam
                    accumsan odio ac lectus mollis finibus.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Aliquam a lectus porta, bibendum enim id, dictum nunc. duis tincidunt
                    sed turpis non suscipit. Nunc id mi molestie, porta leo id, vulputate eros.
                </p>
            </div>
            <hr class="clear">
            <div class="article">
                <h1>Our Best Awesome Article #3</h1>
                <img src="image/gambar3.jpg">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. integer mi
                    tortor, imperdiet sed hendrit non, consequat luctus magna. nullam
                    accumsan odio ac lectus mollis finibus.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Aliquam a lectus porta, bibendum enim id, dictum nunc. duis tincidunt
                    sed turpis non suscipit. Nunc id mi molestie, porta leo id, vulputate eros.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br class="clear">

        
        <div class="footer">
            <p class="copyright">Copyright Awesome Website 2021</p>
            <ul class="footermenu">
                <li><a href="#">Term of Use</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Disclaimer</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: done guys, no need answear question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the image what I understood is, you want the width of the dropdown to be same as that of the 'li' above.

So you can make following changes

```
.nav ul li{position: relative;}

.nav ul li:hover .submenu{width: 100%; left: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your CSS (in `.nav ul li:hover .submenu2 li`) you have the line `text-align: center;`. This centers the text horizontally creating the gap in smaller text. Change this to `text-align: left;` to make sure it starts everything at the same horizontal distance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can add this property, which tells html to resize element to it's *width* including padding:
`*{box-size: border-box;}`
Don't forget to add strict rule for box width for every element. It can be in %, px, rem or whatever you want.

Do not forget, that submenu items have padding that is not equal to it's parent, so that's why submenu is moved. You can use this code to fix this:
`.submenu ul, .submenu li {width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;}`

If this doesn't solve your problem, be free to comment below.